# Python webapp2: get value of variable of RequestHandler class

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

I have a subclass of RequestHandler:

```
class GetStats(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    somevar = None
    def post(self):
        ...
        somevar = "somevalue"
```

And there is creating of instance of this class:

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/stats', GetStats),
], debug=True)
```

So my question: how I can get the value of somevar outside class GetStats?

I have no name of instance of this class.

It is possible without saving this value to global var?

Some **UPDATE:**

It is possible to create certain instance of `class Route`:

```
mp = webapp2.Route('/', handler=MainPage)
gs = webapp2.Route('/stats', handler=GetStats)
```

And initialize `application` by this way:

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([mp,gs], debug=True)
```

But anyway there is no name of instance of GetStats class.

Is there any instantiation in this case `handler=GetStats`?

How it is possible to create instance of GetStats directly?

Comment: You can access `somevar` via `GetStats.somevar` outside of the class. See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects for more details or clarify your question if that's not what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every request new instance of handler are created.

The only way to solve this problem is saving of the handler instance in the request registry.

Alternative way: using webapp2 registry

```
class GetStats(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        ...
        somevar = "somevalue"
        application.registry['variable'] = somevar
        ...


# outside class
application.registry.get('variable')
```

This way allow to avoid global variables in modules.

Comment: What is the request registry?

Comment: Cheers i didnt know about that yet

Answer (score 0):

You could write it to the datastore:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class someVarClass(db.Model):
  somevarField = db.StringProperty(required=True)

class GetStats(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    somevar = None
    def post(self):
        ...

        somevar = "somevalue"
        u = someVarClass(somevarField= somevar)
        u.put()
```

Comment: This isn't a wrong answer, but it is not very performant. If you were to choose a datastore to solve the problem, memcache would be a better choice.